# Javascript filter by X values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, javascript-objects

I have a simple javascript array of objects.

`const obj = [ { id:1, color:'red' }, { id:2, color:'black' }, { id:3, color:'purple' }, { id:4, color:'grey' }, { id:5, color:'white' } ]`

Let's say i have an array : colors = ['red','black'].

I want to filter obj but not like this way => obj.filter(o=>o.color==='black' || o.color==='red').

It depends on how much color in the colors array...

Comment: `obj.filter(o => colors.includes(o.color))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mix of `filter()` with `findIndex()`:

```js
const obj = [ { id:1, color:'red' }, { id:2, color:'black' }, { id:3, color:'purple' }, { id:4, color:'grey' }, { id:5, color:'white' } ];

const colors = ['red','black'];


let ans = obj.filter(x => colors.indexOf(x.color) > -1);

console.log(ans);

let ans2 = obj.filter(x => colors.includes(x.color));

console.log(ans2);
```

Comment: Why not just `includes`?

Comment: thank you it works for me

Comment: @JOo Sure. Please consider green tick the answer to accept it. Consider upvoting.

Comment: You can use `includes` too as mentioned by CherryDT

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.includes` along with `Array.filter`

```js
const obj = [ { id:1, color:'red' }, { id:2, color:'black' }, { id:3, color:'purple' }, { id:4, color:'grey' }, { id:5, color:'white' } ];
const colors = ['red','black'];
const output = obj.filter(node => colors.includes(node.color));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

This one can handle multiple criterias.

```js
const obj = [ { id:1, color:'red' }, { id:2, color:'black' }, { id:3, color:'purple' }, { id:4, color:'grey' }, { id:5, color:'white' } ]

document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var terms=document.getElementById("term").value.split(' ');
  var filtered =[];
  obj.forEach(function(v){
    terms.forEach(function(t){
      if(v.color.includes(t)){
        filtered.push(v);
        return false;
      };
    });
  });
  
  console.log(filtered);
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='term'><button id='filter'>Filter</button>
```